# how to install typescript definitions from github repo

Tags: typescript, aurelia, typescript-typings

how do you install the typescript defs for a library like aurelia-validatejs?

Like the  I did the `npm install aurelia-validatejs --save` to add it to the `package.json` and `node_modules` folders. Is there a typings command to get the typescript definitions into the `typings.json` and `typings/globals` folder? If not how can I do it.

The library src and typescript exports are located at in the [aurelia/validatejs github repo](https://github.com/aurelia/validatejs/tree/master/dist)

In case its relevant, I am playing in a project based on the [aurelia webpack-typescript skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack) and I want to get validatejs and or other plugins working! It would be really cool if there was a blog post showing how to do plug in installs into the webpack-typescript skelton.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a command:

```
typings install github:aurelia/validatejs/dist/aurelia-validatejs.d.ts#ee3479eb6edacb31e2a1b7fdc8871e615970d293 --save --global
```

Or you can manually add it to your `typings.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": false,
    "globalDependencies": {
        "aurelia-validatejs": "github:aurelia/validatejs/dist/aurelia-validatejs.d.ts#ee3479eb6edacb31e2a1b7fdc8871e615970d293"
    }
}
```

And run `typings install` after this.

From [documentation](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md) (see "Valid Locations")

`aurelia/validatejs` - is org/repo

`dist/aurelia-validatejs.d.ts` - is the path

`ee3479eb6edacb31e2a1b7fdc8871e615970d293` - is a commit

Answer (score 0):

Use this command, this will surely helpful

```
typings install package_name --ambient --save
```

It will save package_name to typings.json, for further reference.